# how to focus on button having data-filter is not all?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using data-filter for buttons.I have different data-filters.

```
    <div>
     <button class="filter " data-filter=".category-3 "  >x</button>
     <button class="filter" data-filter=".category-4,.category-2">y</button>
     <button class="filter" data-filter="all">z</button> 
   </div>
```

so  whenever my page gets loaded focus goes to the z button which is having data-filter all.i want focus on the first button X.Is there any way to keep the focus on other than data-filter="all"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set focus on first button use

autofocus

```
<button id="Btn_1" class="filter " data-filter=".category-3 " autofocus >x</button>

 <button id="Btn_2" class="filter" data-filter=".category-4,.category-2">y</button>
 <button id="Btn_3" class="filter" data-filter="all">z</button>
```

or in function use like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Btn_1").focus();
});
```

Check the  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S9WQv/449/) here

Comment: It is not working.Not focusing on any of the buttons

Comment: Its working on my pc,Please update your question with current codes,Let me check it

Comment: I think you get me my frnd @Tejas Masurkar

Comment: By default, when MixItUp first loads, it shows all the target elements. That means, the button with the custom attribute data-filter="all" is triggered. Moreover, the plugin applies a class of active to this button. I read this @vijay

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button').filter(function() {
  return $(this).attr('data-filter') != 'all';
}).first().focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="filter " data-filter=".category-3 ">x</button>
  <button class="filter" data-filter=".category-4,.category-2">y</button>
  <button class="filter" data-filter="all">z</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not focusing anywhere and i am able to see data for z only after putting this code